# Waiting until application return Sucess or Failure(AsyncCallBack)

Tags: gwt, asynchronous, gwtp

Just for example, let's check the code below

```
private void loadUserFromServer() {
    dispatchAsync.execute(new FindLoggedUserAction(),
          new AsyncCallback<FindLoggerUserResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
             //do something
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(BuscarUsuarioLogadoResult result) {
           //dosomething with user
           result.getUser();

       }
       operationTwo();
}
```

My problem is, I have to execute operationTwo(); after some result of dipatcher(Success or failure).

*This is just an example, let's assume I can't put operationTwo() inside the onSucess or onFailure()*

My real PROBLEM

My GateKeeper of presenters that user must be login.

```
private UserDTO user;
@Override
public boolean canReveal() {
        if(getUser() == null){
            ShowMsgEvent.fire(eventBus,"Must Login first", AlertType.ERROR);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
public UserDTO getUser()
{
    if(user == null) 
    {
        //call server
        loadUserFromServer();
    }
    return user;
}
 private void loadUsuarioFromServer() {
    dispatchAsync.execute(new BuscarUsuarioLogadoAction()
     ,new AsyncCallback<BuscarUsuarioLogadoResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
             //something
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(BuscarUsuarioLogadoResult result) {
            if(!(result.getDto().equals(user)))
            {
                setUsuario(result.getDto(), false); //Set user UserDTO user
                //event for update Presenter Login/Logout
                // and Label with username
                fireUserUpdateEvents();
            }
            else
            {
                setUsuario(result.getDto(), false);
            }
        }
    });
```

As you can see, when a Presenter with that Gatekeeper is called and user is null,
getUser() is called, but when dispatch executes, the method doesn't wait until the return of Sucess or Failure

Result: getUser() returns null.

After the sucessful result of dispatch, getUser() returns a DTO. But, as you can see canReveal() already returned false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not think that GateKeeper is a good approach to handle security in your case. You will not be able to reach stable work. Problem that you will have:

1. You are not handling network connection lost. If you code is already cached but you need to reload User it will be a big problem with double checking.
2. Sync calls are always problematic, specially with bad network connection. You will have tons of not responding messages.

To handle presenter access it will be better to use revealInParent method. Most of your presenter already overrides it and it looks like:

```
@Override
protected void revealInParent() {
    RevealContentEvent.fire(...);
}
```

So you can just not fire Reveal event before you actually download user data. In your case the code will looks like:

```
 @Override
 protected void revealInParent() {
   if(getUser() == null){
        RevealContentEvent.fire(...);
        return;
   }  
   dispatchAsync.execute(new BuscarUsuarioLogadoAction()
   ,new AsyncCallback<BuscarUsuarioLogadoResult>() {
      @Override
      public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
           //something
      }

      @Override
      public void onSuccess(BuscarUsuarioLogadoResult result) {
        if(!(result.getDto().equals(user)))
        {
            setUsuario(result.getDto(), false); //Set user UserDTO user
            //event for update Presenter Login/Logout
            // and Label with username
            fireUserUpdateEvents();
        }
        else
        {
            setUsuario(result.getDto(), false);
        }
        RevealContentEvent.fire(...);
      }
   });
```

Comment: hmm... This look better. I'll try to update one Presenter with this code and post result. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We have also encountered similar problems. Its better to use Async call chaining. Since you can't do that there are two options for your problem

1. Setup a timer which will check from time to time whether the user is null or not and return only after when user is populated.
2. Use JSNI (Native code) and make the synchronous call. But beware this is bad practice

Comment: I'll try to do a synchoronous call. Or maybe try another metrics to redirect user to #home;

Comment: It is not recommended to make the synchronous call unless you have a strong reason, that is why GWT has hardcoded  the value and it is always asynchronous

Comment: I know, my idea is to check the second time if the user is null. Only in the second one the server already finished the call.

Comment: Setting a timer and toggling it off is your only feasible solution. Never go with sync calls as they freeze browser in a lot of scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as Abhijith mentioned in previous answer there are 2 options - 
1) Synchronous calls - which GWT doesn't support. So it is ruled out.
2) Setting timer - unless user logs in control will not come out of the timer loop. So failed status will never return from the timer. This approach serves only half of your requierment(serving only success state).

To solve your problem you try the following code snippet -

```
private UserDTO user;
private CanRevealCallBack revealCallBack; 

public interface CanRevealCallBack {
     returnStatus(boolean status);
}

@Override
public void canReveal(CanRevealCallBack callBack) {
    revealCallBack = callBack;
    if(user == null){
          loadUserFromServer();       
    }
    else{
          revealCallBack.returnStatus( true );
    }
}

private void loadUsuarioFromServer() {
dispatchAsync.execute(new BuscarUsuarioLogadoAction()
 ,new AsyncCallback<BuscarUsuarioLogadoResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
         //something
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(BuscarUsuarioLogadoResult result) {
        if(!(result.getDto().equals(user)))
        {
            setUsuario(result.getDto(), false); //Set user UserDTO user
            //event for update Presenter Login/Logout
            // and Label with username
            fireUserUpdateEvents();
        }
        else
        {
            setUsuario(result.getDto(), false);
        }

        if(result.getDto() == null){
            revealCallBack.returnStatus( true );  
        }
        else{
            revealCallBack.returnStatus( false ); 
        }
    }
});
```

So, you have to pass a revealCallback to the canReveal method. CallBack gets executed and returns u the status on success of the async call. In returnStatus method of the callback you can program the logic with the correct user log-in status.

Comment: canReveal its an obligate method from GateKeeper, I can't modify its signature. Whitch is boolean onReveal()
This won't fix.
Thanks anyway.